# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

The GET method is not supported for this route.

> Supported methods: POST.

when I Click on `<a href="">`-tag.

I want post data.

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('trialdetails')}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="zipcode" value="90002">  
    <a href="{{route('trialdetails')}}">View Trial Details</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Why would you expect the request to be a POST when you click on the link? Links are always using GET. You do know that putting a link inside a form won't submit the form, right? You either need to put a proper submit button in there or override the default action for the link using javascript and use Ajax to post the data.

Comment: remove the link and add a button

Answer (score 2):

You should use `<input type="submit">`

but if it is your requirement to use it with anchor tag try below code

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('trialdetails')}}" id="myform">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="zipcode" value="90002">  
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();">View Trial Details</a>
</form>
```

Hope this will serve your purpose

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change this to a button

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('trialdetails')}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="zipcode" value="90002">  
    <input type="submit" value="View Trial Details"></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Links always use `GET` request. So remove anchor tag and use button to submit form.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="logout-form" method="POST" action="{{route('logout')}}">
   @csrf
   <a onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout- 
   form').submit();" href="{{route('logout')}}">Logout</a>
</form>
```

you can just use javaScript instead

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).